# Background color of an activity doesnt change in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

Background color of a MainActivity doesn't response.Background always comes in light black color. Here, I'm attaching my style, themes, manifest, MainActivity and themeUtil snippet.Please have a look and tell me where am I doing mistake.

Actually I removed style="?pagebackground" and given android:background="#ffBE80FF" in activity.xml.The background changes to light purple color but again I reverted it same light black color is coming. Any Idea why it is happening.
Please help me to sort out this issue.

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="?pageBackground"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >
```

manifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

apptheme_activated_background_holo_dark.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_list_activated_holo" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" />
</selector>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="page_background_pur">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_activated_background_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

themes.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/RobotoAutoCompleteTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/RobotoEditTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="pageBackground">@style/page_background_pur</item>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ThemeUtil.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

ThemeUtil.java

```
/** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
        switch (sTheme) {
        default:
        case THEME_PURPLE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            break;
        case NOT_THEME_PURPLE:
            /*activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);*/
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, and what about the activity_main layout? what background color do you have there?

Comment: You should set theme after `setContentView`

Comment: i have use style="?pageBackground" in activity.xml @Cata

Comment: Tried by setting theme after setContentView...But doesn't worked.@Rustam